# Return of promise inside forEach

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, angular-promise

```
function getNamesById(nameIds) {
    var defer = $q.defer();

    var result = [];
    nameIds.forEach(function (nameId) {
        account.getNameById(nameId).then(function (name) {
            result[nameId] = name;
        });
    });
    defer.resolve(result);
    return defer.promise;
}
```

I have the above code witch is obviously not working as expected.
I have to iterate an array of id's and construct another array having the id's as keys, and the values taken from an async function

Comment: You [cannot use `forEach` with promises](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37576685/1048572). Also, avoid the [deferred antipattern](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it)!

Comment: Thank you Jamiec and @Bergi

Comment: @JaromandaX `forEach` + `push` is so ugly that I don't want to consider it :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should just return another promise by using `$q.all`

```
function getNamesById(nameIds) {

    var result = [];
    nameIds.forEach(function (nameId) {
        result.push(account.getNameById(nameId));
    });
    return $q.all(result);
}
```

and then chain that on elsewhere

```
getNamesById(someNameIds)
     .then(...);
```

---

A clearer way to write this is using `.map` instead of declaring an array and using `forEach` to push into it:

```
function getNamesById(nameIds) {
    return $q.all(nameIds.map(function (nameId) {
        return account.getNameById(nameId)
    }));
}
```

If using ES6 (and your method definitely ignores all but the first argument) this can be simplified further:

```
let getNamesById = nameIds => Promise.all(nameIds.map(account.getNameById));
```

---

So from comments, I surmise that you're trying to get an associative array back with `nameId` as the key and the result of the async call as the value. There is one more step you require - You need to *return* a value from your `then` which you can consume later

```
function getNamesById(nameIds) {
    return $q.all(nameIds.map(function (nameId) {
        return account.getNameById(nameId)
                    .then(function(name){
                        return {id:nameId, name:name};
                     })
    }));
}
```

When you consume this method, you can easily `reduce` the result to your associative array

```
getNamesById(["a","b","c"])
    .then(function(results){
        var values = results.reduce(function(p,n){
            p[n.id] = n.name;
            return p;
        },{});
        // values is your associative array with keys a,b & c
     });
```

Written out in ES6 makes this much less verbose - for completeness:

```
function getNamesById(nameIds) {
    return $q.all(nameIds.map(
               nameId => account.getNameById(nameId)
                    .then(name => ({id:nameId, name:name}))
    );
}
```

and

```
getNamesById(["a","b","c"])
    .then(results => {
        var values = results.reduce((p,n) => {
            p[n.id] = n.name;
            return p;
        },{});
        // values is your associative array with keys a,b & c
     });
```

Comment: using `nameIds.map(account.getNameById)` can be problematic if function `account.getNameById` doesn't ignore all but the first argument (I've been stung **once** like that :p (what is a P/A rant?)

Comment: @JaromandaX thanks. Answer updated. Your addition to your answer was *very* [passive/agressive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passive-aggressive_behavior) and seemed directed at me by the quote `apparently just blurting out the answer first is the accepted way these days`. My answer was far from "blurted out" - but may have been missing a bit of detail which I admit should have been included in the first place.

Comment: wasn't intended that way - so many accepted answers seem to be the quickest rather than the best (in my opinion) - perhaps it's my opinion that is at fault :p

Comment: @JaromandaX It's a well known problem here. You're not the first to point it out.

Comment: I used the forEach approach because I needed an associative array with the nameId as the key, and name as value

Comment: @uromay then you want `.reduce` not `.map` but you need an array of promises to pass to `$q.all` in any case! so somewhere or other you'll have a `.map`